# Math operations from string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to find a simple way to perform a set of javascript math operations without using eval() function. Example: **1+2x3x400+32/2+3** and it must follow the PEMDAS math principle. This is what I have, but it doesn't work exactly it should.

```
function mdas(equation) {

    let operations = ["*", "/", "+", "-"];

    for (let outerCount = 0; outerCount < operations.length; outerCount++) {
        for (let innerCount = 0; innerCount < equation.length; ) {
            if (equation[innerCount] == operations[outerCount]) {

                let operationResult = runOperation(equation[innerCount - 1], operations[outerCount], equation[innerCount + 1]);

                var leftSideOfEquation = equation.substr(0, equation.indexOf(innerCount - 1));
                var rightSideOfEquation = equation.substr(equation.indexOf(innerCount), equation.length);
                
                var rightSideOfEquation = rightSideOfEquation.replace(rightSideOfEquation[0],String(operationResult));
                equation = leftSideOfEquation + rightSideOfEquation;
                innerCount = 0;
            }
            else {
                innerCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return "Here is it: " + equation; //result of the equation
}
```

Comment: Can you describe some example cases where your code isn't working as it should?

Comment: @kylejrp The current example doesn't work and using something as simple as 1+2*3*4+1+1+3 does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hacky, but you can try something like this:

```js
var eqs = [
'1+2*3*4+1+1+3',
'1+2*3*400+32/2+3',
'-5+2',
'3*-2',
];

for(var eq in eqs) { console.log(mdas(eqs[eq])); }

function mdas(equation) {

console.log(equation);

var failsafe = 100;
var num = '(((?<=[*+-])-|^-)?[0-9.]+)';
var reg = new RegExp(num + '([*/])' + num);

while(m = reg.exec(equation)) {
    var n = (m[3] == "*") ? m[1]*m[4] : m[1]/m[4];
    equation = equation.replace(m[0], n);
    if(failsafe--<0) { return 'failsafe'; } 
}

var reg = new RegExp(num + '([+-])' + num);
while(m = reg.exec(equation)) {
    var n = (m[3] == "+") ? 1*m[1] + 1*m[4] : m[1]-m[4];
    equation = equation.replace(m[0], n);
    if(failsafe--<0) { return 'failsafe'; }
}

return equation;

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225062/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-strickland-math-operations-from-string-using-javas).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a complete library like [mathjs](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs) - and you don't want to tackle creating your own script which would involve: lexical analysis, tokenization, syntax analysis, recursive tree parsing, compiling and output...
the simplest banal suggestion: [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```js
const calc = s => Function(`return(${s})`)();

console.log( calc("1+2*3*400+32/2+3") ); // 2420
console.log( calc("-3*-2") );            // 6
console.log( calc("-3 * + 1") );         // -3
console.log( calc("-3 + -1") );          // -4
console.log( calc("2 * (3 + 1)") );      // 8
```

### My take at a custom MDAS

- [Here I created](https://regex101.com/r/GUF0bo/1) a **Regex to retrieve operands and operators**, accounting for negative values: `/(-?[\d.]+)([*\/+-])?/g`.
- Firstly we need to **remove any whitespace** from our string using `str.replace(/ /g , "")`
- Using JavaScript's [String.prototype.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) we can get a *2D* array with all the matches as `[[fullMatch, operand, operator], [.. ]` we can than further flatten it using [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- Having that flattened array, we can now filter it using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the fullMatch *-es* returned by the regular expression and remove the last `undefined` value.
- Define a `calc` Object with the needed operation functions
- Iterate over the MDAS groups `*/` and than `+-` as regular expressions `/\/*/` and `/+-/`
- Consume finally the array of matches until only one array key is left

```js
let str = "-1+2 * 3*+400+-32 /2+3.1";   // 2386.1
str = str.replace(/ +/g, "");           // Remove all spaces!

// Get operands and operators as array.
// Remove full matches and undefined values.
const m = [...str.matchAll(/(-?[\d.]+)([*\/+-])?/g)].flat().filter((x, i) => x && i % 3);

const calc = {
  "*": (a, b) => a * b,
  "/": (a, b) => a / b,
  "+": (a, b) => a + b,
  "-": (a, b) => a - b,
};

// Iterate by MDAS groups order (first */ and than +-)
[/[*\/]/, /[+-]/].forEach(expr => {
  for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i += 2) {
    let [a, x, b] = [m[i], m[i + 1], m[i + 2]];
    x = expr.exec(x);
    if (!x) continue;
    m[i] = calc[x.input](parseFloat(a), parseFloat(b)); // calculate and insert
    m.splice(i + 1, 2);                                 // remove operator and operand
    i -= 2;                                             // rewind loop
  }
});

// Get the last standing result
console.log(m[0]);      // 2386.1
```

Comment: @Nation: I can probably handle the negative numbers after operators with a positive lookbehind in the regex, but considering how clean this is I don't know that there's any point.  Look good to you?

Comment: @ChrisStrickland the regex is pretty simple actually. I'm giving it a try too... for fun... Will update soon

Comment: I did update my example to handle for negative numbers with an alteration to the regex, but it won't handle explicitly positive numbers or parentheses or exponents.  I could fix the regex to handle explicitly positive numbers like 3 * + 1 (as in your example) and parentheses can be handled with a little bit of reflexiveness, and exponents with one more while loop, but considering your solution is awesome, I don't think I will.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland I think I got something. Handles spaces, negatives and all sort of stuff - besides parenthesis and exp.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this is awesome! I really good to understand the science behind how simple math work and how we can use a programming language to achieve its basic calculations.

Comment: Both answers are great and showing different ways to be creative in order to solve the problem.

Comment: @Nation writing complex code becomes an art. Well spotted.