# Why javascript calculator don't show correct operator?

Tags: javascript, frontend, calculator

I am at the very beginning of the learning process of web development.
I'm doing the odin project and I am at the task what wants me to make a basic calculator.

I have figured out many things and made it work but if the user adds a half expression like 3+ and after this press the -, *, or / buttons the display shows NaN. It is bad.

I'd like that if the user puts in for example 3+ and after it he press the - button the display should show 3- and make a substract after the second value added.

I cannot figure it out now.. but I'm sure it is trivial..

Here is my project:

https://github.com/JohnyKidd/calculator

Here is the code snippet which may be the problem. This is where I add values to the display. It is the same for all four basic operations:

```
plusButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if (display.value.includes("+")||display.value.includes("-")||display.value.includes("*")||display.value.includes("/")){
    eval = display.value.split("+");
    console.log(eval);
    for(let i=0;i<eval.length;i++){
      eval[i]=parseFloat(eval[i]);
      result=eval[0]+eval[1];
    }
    console.log(eval);
    display.value=result;
    result=0;
  }
  else {
    display.value+="+";
  }
});
```

Sorry for my messy code. I know it must be improved. I will try to improve myself.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Please post the part of the code here as text that you're having issues with.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive)

Comment: PS... Instead of using N images you could have used just a single spritesheet.png and CSS `background-position`

Comment: PS: **STOP** using inline `on*` JS handler attributes, the same way you (hopefully)
don't use inline `style` attributes.
JS and CSS should be in one place only
and that's their respective tags or files.
Use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
instead.

Comment: Sorry about the bad editing. I have added the code snippet where I think the problem is.

Comment: Roko C. Buljan, thank you for the advice. I appreciate criticism because as you see I'm not an advanced coder.

Comment: No worries, (it was not a criticism, it was a heartly alert! <3) `eval = display.value.split("+");` what do you think this line of code does? Also, don't use global variables like that. Use rather a variable that tells what it does: `const splittedByPlus = display.value.split("+");`

Comment: Is this answer helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64979176/383904

Comment: Heartly alerts are appreciated too (and everything what can build my knowledge).

eval = display.value.split("+"); => It splits the string at + (also deletes the plus). Makes a character array from it with two elements. I did it this way because the project specification asks me to do only x+y or x-y or x*y or x/y at once and no more. I'm sure it is not the best way to do this but it seemed handy back then to split, convert, and evaluate the user input.

Comment: @Archmage took me some time to review your git code. You have too many code repetitions. I'll try to  put up some answer soon hopefully.

Comment: Roko, I ,,resolved" the error I mentioned. It works now... Not like a charm but it works. I appreciate your help. This code is a mess. A real spaghetti. I can find things in it because I wrote it but if I would give it to other developer, he/she maybe get nausea from it. Thank you for your help and sorry for bad coding. I'll try improve my code and use functions, loops next time because after this project I can see that it is the only reasonable way to move forward. Sorry if I caused you head or eye injuries. I didn't want to.